# How to configure spring boot back end to accept request only from amazon API Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk accessible through API Gateway, I have enabled client side SSL certificate authentication. But I am confused on how my backend will authenticate with the public key I have ? I just have the public key to authenticate the request. Will help if there is a code snippet.

Assume this is my Controller, How can I verify the request using public key when a request hits this API.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

  @RequestMapping(path = "/test")
  public String get() {
    return "Hello";
  }

}
```

Comment: Add a filter to intercept every request hitting your server and honour only those requests that are coming from specific URL like https://amazon.com/***

Comment: @SumitBadaya request coming from amazon won't help. Because then there is not point of using SSL certificate. Is there a better approach ?

Comment: What do you mean by no point of using SSL?
How does your Java's Filter interceptor comes in the way of SSL?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean you were wrong. You are absolutely right. But the requirement is different. If you go through the description again, I want client-side SSL authentication in my backend application.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html